# why communication between nodes in ej2 DiagramComponent may not be established?

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I'm trying to create a connection between nodes using a **datamanager**
But when I specify **connectionDataSource**, the nodes disappear and the screen is empty, there are no errors in the console

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-relationship-playground-component',
  template: `<ejs-diagram id="diagram" width="100%" height="580px" [layout]='layout' [dataSourceSettings]='dataSourceSettings' [getNodeDefaults]='nodeDefaults' [getConnectorDefaults]='connectorDefaults'>
  </ejs-diagram>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RelationshipPlaygroundComponentComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild("diagram") public layout?: LayoutModel;
  public dataSourceSettings?: DataSourceModel;

  public connections : Object[] =  [
    {
      id: "a96b708d-9878-409b-9424-79afd536fbcb",
      source: "e0ad8a67-65a4-488e-a13e-af4a51095da4",
      target: "991d0d06-f084-43df-871d-2c501a41108e",
    }
  ]

  public elements : Object[] = [
    {
      caption: "Accom (sample)",
      id: "e0ad8a67-65a4-488e-a13e-af4a51095da4",
      recordId: "405947d0-2ffb-4ded-8675-0475f19f5a81",
    },
    {

      caption: "Our company",
      id: "991d0d06-f084-43df-871d-2c501a41108e",
      recordId: "e308b781-3c5b-4ecb-89ef-5c1ed4da488e",
    }
  ]

  public nodeDefaults(node: NodeModel): NodeModel {
    return node;
  }

  public connectorDefaults(connector: ConnectorModel): ConnectorModel {
    connector.type = "Orthogonal";
    connector.cornerRadius = 7;
    return connector;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.layout = {
      type: "HierarchicalTree", verticalSpacing: 40
    };
    this.dataSourceSettings = {
      id: "id",
      dataManager: new DataManager(this.elements as JSON[]),
      connectionDataSource: {
        id: 'id',
        sourceID: 'source',
        targetID: 'target',
        dataManager: new DataManager(this.connections as JSON[])
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I took examples from the documentation and the sample repository
https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-samples/blob/master/src/diagram/crud.ts

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/diagram/data-binding#how-to-perform-editing-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hierarchical Tree layout using DataManager has been rendered. In DataManager, you need to assign a JSON object with Id and parentId, and this DataManager is then assigned to the dataSource property in dataSourceSettings. The layout is rendered based on the ID and parentId defined in the layout. When rendering the layout, there is no need to set a connectionDataSource.

Documentation
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/diagram/automatic-layout

Sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzj1jr-87pxp8?file=src%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My connections and nodes come from the backend in separate parts. And I would like to know if it is possible to draw a conclusion using dataSourceSettings, simply specifying the model for nodes and connections, and specifying what connections they should be based on, as can be seen from my example

Comment: Also in the presented question there is a link to a repository with a possible implementation, but it is made for obtaining data from the network, not local

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).